# Модель телеметрии iot

Tags: база-данных, cassandra, iot

Ребята, поделитесь мыслями по возникшей задачке.

Задачка: спроектировать модель данных под Cassandra для телеметрии iot устройств. Iot устройства различаются по типу устройства, модели и версии прошивки) атрибутный состав телеметрии может меняться в зависимости от прошивки.

Каким образом построить модель данных?

Были предложения по хранению телеметрии в отдельной колонке (data) в виде json структуры, но это предложение отвергли, мол, еще будут сервисы, которые должны запрашивать данные телеметрии из БД с учетом фильтрации, агрегации

Comment: в кассандре все крутится вокруг запросов - составьте список запросов к этой базе, и от них пляшите